# How to solve "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0."

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, gradle, build.gradle

When I import my component to our project, "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0." occurred.

**code here**

```
object MyCameraX {
  private const val api = "com.xxx.xxx.camera:api:0.0.3-alpha02"
  val impl = arrayOf(api)
}
```

```
implementation MyCameraX.api
```

I would really appreciate it if you could provide a helpful answer!

**What I tried before**

I tried changing the dependencies version in my component to our projects', but that didn't work.
It looks like the component has three dependencies more than our project and one dependency version higher that our project.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0' //version higher than project(1.3.0)
// the dependencies our project doesn't have
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-video:1.2.3")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.2.3")
api 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
```